# Keynote - playing slide - three finger swipe won't switch applications

Tags: macos, keynote, multi-touch

When I'm in the middle of a keynote presentation playing - the three finger swipe to switch applications no longer works. When I exit playing the presentation - it works again. I run Keynote '09 on OS X Lion.

Is there a way to make three finger swipe work in the middle of a presentation without stopping and starting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three finger swipe won't work in Keynote 2013.

There is quite a complicated way to exit and flip applications [here](http://viget.com/inspire/level-up-your-presentation-my-almost-seamless-transition-from-keynote-to-a).

There is a simple way to flip to the last used application [by pressing H](http://dashkards.com/keynote).